# Comparing A Variable Number of Arguments With A For Loop

Tags: variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a function that can be given any number of cryptocurrency names. The function will use the arguments to scrape data from CoinMarketCap.com. Since I'm only wanting to compare the close value of each cryptocurrency (and only for today's date) I've defined the days date as a string which I can input into the date section of the url in the correct format.

However, I've got to a point where I'm unsure how to correctly return the results. My intention is for the final 'crypto' variable of the for loop to consist of a dictionary containing the day's data of a respective cryptocurrency. Then, using this variable, I'd like to be able to compare the values of however many cryptocurrencies I choose as arguments in my function. How would I continue with the function to make this possible? I was thinking of using Numpy so I could compare the data using arrays? Though, I'm open to better suggestions if there are any.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
def compare_close(*cryptos):
    for crypto in cryptos:
        date = str(datetime.date.today())
        date = date.replace('-', '')
        url = f"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{crypto}/historical-data/?start={date}&end={date}"
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
        table = tree.find_class('cmc-table')[0]
        xpath_0, xpath_1 = 'div[3]/div/table/thead/tr', 'div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[%d]/div'
        cols = [c.text_content() for c in table.xpath(xpath_0 + '/th')]
        dates = (d.text_content() for d in table.xpath(xpath_1 % 1))
        m = map(lambda d: (float(_.text_content().replace(',', '')) for _ in table.xpath(xpath_1 % d)),
                range(2, 8))
        crypto = [{k: v for k, v in zip(cols, _)} for _ in zip(dates, *m)]
        return crypto
```